# SQL While loop select all rows that have a column checked

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a featured car section in my used car lot website.

What I want to do is to use a while loop and select only the rows that have a specific column that returns true. For example, in my database, I have a column that is marked true if a checkbox on the submit form is ticked indicating that the car is supposed to be "featured".

In my while loop I only want those cars to appear in this particular section. Using the code below, I can return all vehicles in the inventory but no way to select only the ones with the "featured" column that returns a true value.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
echo '<div class="slide">';
echo '<div class="car-block">';
echo '<div class="img-flex">';
echo '<a href="inventory-listing.php?vin='.$row['vin'].'">';
echo '<span class="align-center">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-3x fa-plus-square-o"></i></span></a>';
echo '<img src="images/inventory/'.$row['vin'].'-main.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="car-block-bottom">';
echo '<h6><strong>'.$row['year'].' '.$row['make'].' '.$row['model'].'</strong></h6>';
echo '<h6>'.$row['body'].', '.$row['milage'].' miles</h6>';
echo '<h5>$ '.$row['price'].'</h5>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

What would I be able to add to my sql query to filter it only the rows where the "featured" column returns true?

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE featured LIMIT 10` (or `WHERE featured = true`). This is assuming that the field featured is a boolean field, or a numeric field with 1 and 0 values, which is common for boolean values. (See [Boolean literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html))

Comment: Both of these solutions should work. I can't believe I was overthinking it that much lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to Goleztrols suggestion, you could just insert an IF clause before echo-ing the results.

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
if ($row['featured']=="true") 
{
echo '<div class="slide">';
echo '<div class="car-block">';
echo '<div class="img-flex">';
echo '<a href="inventory-listing.php?vin='.$row['vin'].'">';
echo '<span class="align-center">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-3x fa-plus-square-o"></i></span></a>';
echo '<img src="images/inventory/'.$row['vin'].'-main.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="car-block-bottom">';
echo '<h6><strong>'.$row['year'].' '.$row['make'].' '.$row['model'].'</strong></h6>';
echo '<h6>'.$row['body'].', '.$row['milage'].' miles</h6>';
echo '<h5>$ '.$row['price'].'</h5>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
else 
{
echo "nothing to be shown";
}
}
```

Comment: Both of these solutions should work. I can't believe I was overthinking it that much lol.